# Why i get table or view does not exist

Tags: oracle, rest

When i want to test a restfull service generated via netbeans i get an error: table or view does not exist. The query to fetch table works properly

```
SELECT TEMPLATE_ID, CREATED_BY, CREATION_DATE, FOLDER_STATE, FOLDER_TYPE, JUSTIFICATION_CODE, LAST_UPDATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_DATE, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, RESPONSE, STATUS FROM CNSS_PROD.HIS_AGR_TEMPLATE;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CNSS_PROD.HIS_AGR_TEMPLATE")
@XmlRootElement
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "HisAgrTemplate.findAll", query = "SELECT h FROM HisAgrTemplate h")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "HisAgrTemplate.findByTemplateId", query = "SELECT h FROM HisAgrTemplate h WHERE h.templateId = :templateId")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "HisAgrTemplate.findByJustificationCode", query = "SELECT h FROM HisAgrTemplate h WHERE h.justificationCode = :justificationCode")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "HisAgrTemplate.findByFolderState", query = "SELECT h FROM HisAgrTemplate h WHERE h.folderState = :folderState")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "HisAgrTemplate.findByFolderType", query = "SELECT h FROM HisAgrTemplate h WHERE h.folderType = :folderType")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "HisAgrTemplate.findByResponse", query = "SELECT h FROM HisAgrTemplate h WHERE h.response = :response")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "HisAgrTemplate.findByStatus", query = "SELECT h FROM HisAgrTemplate h WHERE h.status = :status")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "HisAgrTemplate.findByCreatedBy", query = "SELECT h FROM HisAgrTemplate h WHERE h.createdBy = :createdBy")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "HisAgrTemplate.findByCreationDate", query = "SELECT h FROM HisAgrTemplate h WHERE h.creationDate = :creationDate")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "HisAgrTemplate.findByLastUpdatedBy", query = "SELECT h FROM HisAgrTemplate h WHERE h.lastUpdatedBy = :lastUpdatedBy")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "HisAgrTemplate.findByLastUpdatedDate", query = "SELECT h FROM HisAgrTemplate h WHERE h.lastUpdatedDate = :lastUpdatedDate")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "HisAgrTemplate.findByLastUpdatedTime", query = "SELECT h FROM HisAgrTemplate h WHERE h.lastUpdatedTime = :lastUpdatedTime")})
public class HisAgrTemplate implements Serializable {
```

```
Call: SELECT TEMPLATE_ID, CREATED_BY, CREATION_DATE, FOLDER_STATE, FOLDER_TYPE, JUSTIFICATION_CODE, LAST_UPDATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_DATE, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, RESPONSE, STATUS FROM CNSS_PROD.HIS_AGR_TEMPLATE
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=HisAgrTemplate sql="SELECT TEMPLATE_ID, CREATED_BY, CREATION_DATE, FOLDER_STATE, FOLDER_TYPE, JUSTIFICATION_CODE, LAST_UPDATED_BY, LAST_UPDATED_DATE, LAST_UPDATED_TIME, RESPONSE, STATUS FROM CNSS_PROD.HIS_AGR_TEMPLATE")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2062)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: Table ou vue inexistante
```

Answer (score 0):

Schema and database (or view) name must be specified separately. `@Table` annotation has `schema` attribute also. So check this:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "HIS_AGR_TEMPLATE", schema="CNSS_PROD")
@XmlRootElement
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
//...
public class HisAgrTemplate implements Serializable {
   //...
}
```

Optionally if the user who connected to the database doesn't have permission to access that table (or view) it could cause the same error message.
In Oracle check these sql scripts' output:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  USER_SYS_PRIVS;
```

or

```sql
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    DBA_ROLE_PRIVS
WHERE grantee = '[username]';
```

Comment: Did you connect to the database with the same account? The answer is right so you should define schema and tablename separately but you get the same error message if the table exists but that account doesn't have permission to access.